# awk, scope when executing cmds in curly brackets

Tags: awk

Right so I have a file which looks like

```
aaa|bbb|ccc
eee|fff|ggg
```

All I want is to to tokenize on '|' and create a map from one index val to another.
eg, if the key is col 1 (not zero based indexing) and the val is col 3, my map should be:

```
aaa -> ccc
eee -> ggg
```

Comment: `awk` is not `bash`, its a different programming language itself you can't access awk's created arrays in bash after its program is done. If you could give more information on what is your Goal here then we may try to help you on same, thank you.

Comment: I want to cat a file that looks like:

aaa|bbb|ccc
eee|fff|ggg

...tokenize on '|' and create a map from one index to another
eg,
aaa -> ccc
eee -> ggg

Maybe awk is not the best option.

Thank you

Comment: Sure, you can update this in your question along with your efforts, so that we could understand it better, thank you.

Comment: Why not move your code inside `awk` instead of extracting the value out?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format the blocks of text (input, output, and code when you add it) in your question.

Comment: Because then I want to use my map when looping through another file.
Having everything in awk seem cumbersome.
Maybe a better question is...how do I get the map in bash?

Comment: Bash is a shell. A shell is a tool to create/destroy files and processes with a language to sequence calls to tools. Awk is the tool that the guys who invented shell also invented for shell to call to manipulate text. Trying to do text manipulation in a shell, if that is what you're doing, is a bad idea (e.g. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for some of the reasons). If you think writing text-processing code in awk would be more cumbersome than in shell then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If you need something in bash then add the bash tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks....I think doing it all in awk is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{map[$1]=$3} END{for (key in map) printf "map[%s]=%s\n", key, map[key]}' file
map[aaa]=ccc
map[eee]=ggg
```

If you had wanted to create a map array in bash:

```
$ declare -A map
$ while IFS='|' read -r key _ val; do map["$key"]="$val"; done < file
$ declare -p map
declare -A map=([eee]="ggg" [aaa]="ccc" )
```

but then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice if you're considering using that for further text processing.